# Screen grids on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, screen

I am looking for an app or Gnome extension to show grids on the screen. I am going to use it mostly in screen capturing to be roughly sure about that I capture the same size and position every time.

Something like that: [image]

When I search about grids for Ubuntu, all the results are about workspace grids so I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Do you want these grids to show up in the screenshot?  If not, it's probably going to have to be a feature of some screenshot application.

Comment: Just use Shutter. It gives you the x & y coordinates when you capture a selected portion of the screen. You can even tell it to redo the shot to ensure it's the same size and position each time. I can write you out a full answer, if you prefer.

Comment: Actually I am not looking for another SS app. I need some kind of an extra layer of grids on the screen so that I can use multipurpose. For instance, I am using a web-based whiteboard app. Such a grid structure on the screen would be very helpful for that purpose, as well.

Comment: make  your own grid with a transparent background. a shortcut key for it to show, and a shortcut to run gnome-screenshot -d 10, you could combine with &&    .. where number is second delay  . further to that something to ignore the grid 'photo' for mouse and keyboard input if for other than simple screenshot purposes.   https://askubuntu.com/questions/50375/apply-transparent-background-in-gimp

Comment: I attached a transparent plastic cover on my screen with some grids on. When I need to do something with rough measurement, I use it for now. This is the most practical for now.

Answer (score 0):

Better late then never...

You can do it using OSD commands :

```
# apt install xosd-bin
```

Then something like :

```
$ for i in {1..65}; do printf '│            %.s' {1..40}; echo; done | osd_cat --delay 0 --lines 65 --font "-*-*-*-*-*-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-*-*" --color yellow &

$ for i in {1..12}; do printf '─%.s' {1..180}; printf '\n%.s' {1..4}; done | osd_cat --delay 0 --lines 50 --font "-*-*-*-*-*-*-18-*-*-*-*-*-*-*" --color yellow &
```

You'll have to find out the right parameters for your needs, depending on your monitor resolution, on the grid size you want, and so on...

Maybe write a script, if you use that often. The result on my 1600x900 monitor :

[image]